# regex : ignore several downstream xml tags

Tags: python, xml, regex

I need to extract **only** with regex , the content of an xml , but by ignoring subtags :

Input is like this :

```
<firstTag>k</firstTag><secondTag>jkjk</secondTag>
<ignoreTag><subIgnoreTag>j</subIgnoreTage>...</ignoreTag>
<ignoreTag><subIgnoreTag>j</subIgnoreTage>...</ignoreTag>
<thirdTage>3<thirdTag>...
```

I would like to have the following :

```
<firstTag>k</firstTag><secondTag>jkjk</secondTag>
<thirdTage>3<thirdTag>...
```

I've tried this :

```
(?P<test>.*)<ignoreTag>
```

to see if I can get the first part at least, but I is only ignoring the last occurrence of `IgnoreTag`...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/14122

Comment: What about `subIgnoreTag`? Why not find this? It has no nested tags.

Comment: `re.sub('<ignoreTag>.*?</ignoreTag>', '', xml_string)`

Comment: More seriously -- if Python is in play here, why "only regex"? Why can't the rest of the Python standard library be used? It's easier to take "only regex" restrictions seriously if they're based on legitimate tool restrictions ("I'm in an environment that has nothing but busybox with ash and grep"). Not using a real parser means your solution is going to have bugs (no, really, it will -- since you can't use regular expressions to accurately parse an irregular language [which, yes, is a technical term w/ a specific meaning], there are always going to be corner cases)... and for what benefit?

Comment: If you want to get only the first part, use not greedy operators. As (?P<test>.*?)<ignoreTag>. But I don't understand what you mean with "ignoring subtags"

Comment: @sharcashmo. He wants a full XML parser using regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

xml = """<firstTag>k</firstTag><secondTag>jkjk</secondTag>
      <ignoreTag><subIgnoreTag>j</subIgnoreTage>...</ignoreTag>
      <ignoreTag><subIgnoreTag>j</subIgnoreTage>...</ignoreTag>
      <thirdTage>3<thirdTag>"""

print(re.sub("<ignoreTag>.*?</ignoreTag>\n?", '', xml))
```